# How to load images from https using the_field

Tags: php, ssl, https

In Wordpress, I have a line of code that loads images form http, and I would like it to load them from https.

```
<img class="img_notif" src="<?php the_field('small_img',$post->ID); ?>" />
```

This is what it does in the page:

```
<img class="img_notif" src="http://www.startupacademy.ro/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/antreprenor-de-succes-mic.jpg" />
```

How can I change the code so I force wordpress to load the image from https?

Answer (score 0):

Since WP doesn't seem to have a native way to do this (I am **shocked** `</sarcasm>`) you can just use PHP to do a replace. Change your line to

```
<img class="img_notif" src="<?php str_replace('http', 'https', the_field('small_img',$post->ID)); ?>" />
```

Comment: Changed the line but couldn't get it to work. Still http